# Сделать ссылки на середину видео через <a>

Tags: html, видео

Подскажите пожалуйста, у меня локально лежит список видео - они очень длинные и резать их нельзя. Я хочу сделать небольшую навигацию по ним через html. Есть ли возможность сделать ссылки на конкретные тайм-коды видеоряда при помощи одного только html?

(Пример от балды)

```
<h1>В поисках Немо</h1>
<a href="мультик_про_немо.мп4_11_минут_15_секунд">Немо потерялся</a>
<a href="мультик_про_немо.мп4_23_минут_33_секунд">Встречаем Дори</a>
<a href="мультик_про_немо.мп4_41_минут_56_секунд">Акула Брюс в бешенстве</a>
```

Если же нельзя быстро и просто, то как можно?

Comment: если плеер не имеет какое-то API, через которое может принимать тайм-код, то этого сделать нельзя

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Видео открывается в новой вкладке Mozilla Firefox. Я в пролёте, да? =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать использовать [HTML5 video fragment URI](https://www.w3.org/TR/media-frags/):

```
<video autobuffer controls>
    <source src="video-sample.mp4#t=00:11:15">
</video>
```

И потом менять `src` видео при нажатии на ссылки/кнопки.

Comment: Спасибо большое, спасли! Сперва напугало то, что видео находится на самой странице, но я завернула его в details. Получается громоздкая конструкция тегов, но я довольна как слон, что не нужно мучиться со скриптами =)